# How thick would a cable have to be for sustained current of 300A?

Tags: cables

#### Background

I'm daydreaming of a future where all cars are electric and wondering how actually feasible it would be. Obviously there are many challenges left for that, but for me (and millions of other people) the biggest practical problem would be - where to charge? It's all nice if you keep your car in a garage where you can leave it charging overnight, but I live in an apartment block without any dedicated parking and just park my car on the side of the nearest street. Obviously there will never be any charging possibilities there, so for me charging would have to be done in a similar manner to refueling my car today - purposefully going to a charge station somewhere to charge my car.

#### The arithmetic

So let's say that the battery capacity is about the same as today - 50 kWh for a typical car. That should be enough for a few days of commute, I think. Now let's also suppose I don't want to spend hours at the charging station. In fact, there would be many people like me so keeping the charging time low is paramount. Let's say - 10 minutes to get those 50 kWh fully charged from near-empty. That's comparable to today's refueling times of gas-powered cars.

That would mean that every minute I charge 5 kWh. Or, to convert it to a different unit, 300 kW-minutes every minute. That works out then to 300 kW of power, not accounting for any losses. Assuming we crank the voltage up to 1000 V, that still leaves us with 300 amps flowing steadily over the next 10 minutes (and then after that for the next client too), etc. Which means that the cable should NOT heat up significantly.

#### The question

Now, ignoring all the other (im)practical aspects of this operation (the batteries that would accept this, the safety requirements for 1 kV charging, the power source of the charging station), **how thick would the cable have to be to steadily handle 300 A without significantly heating up**? And would a human be able to actually move it and plug it in a car?

Additional considerations: Obviously this depends on the material of the cable. Trying to look up some information on the internet I could at best find that silver is the best conductor, but it's followed closely by copper. So I'm curious about the numbers for both of these. Cables made out of pure silver would, of course, be ridiculously expensive, but let's ignore that for now. In addition, maybe there is some even better conductor available - if so, I'd like to know about that. But I'm only interested in realistically feasible (even if expensive) materials, so exotics like cryogenically frozen superconductors are off the table. (Although... perhaps it would be possible to make a cable that contains a thin superconductor in the centre, surrounded by a coolant or something?)

Comment: Go and have a look at your house service feed to/from the main meter. Thats the sort of cable you are talking about at 300A.

Comment: https://electrek.co/2019/09/30/tesla-patents-liquid-cooled-charging-connector/

Comment: basically jumper cables...

Comment: If you're talking about how easily it can be moved, aluminum is superior to copper--though the cable will be thicker, it will be lighter just due to how light aluminum is. Beryllium, sodium, and lithium are all even better than aluminum in that regard, but beryllium is horrendously toxic and sodium and lithium both rapidly react with both air and water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how thick would the cable have to be to steadily handle 300 A without
> significantly heating up? And would a human be able to actually move
> it and plug it in a car?

It would be about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Supercharger) thick - and yes, a human can actually move it and plug it into a car.

[image]

> A Tesla Supercharger is a **480-volt** direct current fast-charging
> technology built by American vehicle manufacturer Tesla, Inc. for
> their all-electric cars... The original V1 and V2 Tesla supercharging
> stations charge with up to **150 kW** of power distributed between two
> cars with a maximum of 150 kW per car

150 kW / 480 V = 312.5 A.

> I'm only interested in realistically feasible (even if expensive)
> materials, so exotics like cryogenically frozen superconductors are
> off the table.

Some Tesla supercharger cables are [liquid cooled](https://www.teslarati.com/tesla-liquid-cooled-supercharger-cables/) with propylene glycol.

> I live in an apartment block without any dedicated parking and just
> park my car on the side of the nearest street. Obviously there will
> never be any charging possibilities there...

There is no *technical* impediment to on-street charging. If enough people want it, it will come.

> ...so for me charging would have to be done **in a similar manner to**
> **refueling my car today - purposefully going to a charge station**
> somewhere to charge my car.

Electric car owners don't waste their time going to a 'gas' station when they have alternatives. Where do you go *to* in your car? If it's electric  you may be able to simply charge it where you park it.

Comment: Whoever dv'ed, please comment as to why!

Comment: It will come. My city has a (temporary) allowance for an extension cord to cross the sidewalk to charge your car in the street. Soon as well as superchargers there will be slowchargers everywhere, like parking meters.

Comment: There's some really ugly social aspects of electric. Provisioning access to fast (or any) charging costs money. As a result, as things stand today that infrastructure is serving a moneyed class who can afford the extra initial cost, can abide the charge time of an electric, and can afford an eventual battery swap when they wear out (or they'll sell the vehicle, and it becomes someone else's problem.) It's a privilege thing and will be for the foreseeable future. Oh, and those parking meters? Going away, replaced with kiosks or parking apps.

Comment: More about that here: https://grist.org/justice/making-electric-cars-more-equitable/

Comment: @hacktastical I have a 10 year old Nissan Leaf which cost me ~US$6000 2 years ago (I live in New Zealand). My battery only has ~95km range, but that's plenty enough for my driving. Due to Covid-19 I have almost no work, and I am not rich so I need to keep my costs down. Maintenance costs on the Leaf are way lower than my last gas car. Electricity is 1/4 the price of gas (which is ~NZ$2.20/l here), cheap enough that friends let me plug in for free while I am visiting them. People who 'can't afford' an electric car pour thousands into crappy old gas cars and never tally up the full costs.

Comment: Yes, it’s feasible to get by with that limited range for some people, with rational density design and reasonable housing costs. That’s not the situation where I live (California), where many people are forced into long commutes due to housing cost and NIMBY-ism zoning that discourages high density and mass transit. These same people are not well-paid, and can’t afford even the lowest-end electric with enough range (say, $33k for a Bolt) to cover a hundred-mile round trip commute with reasonable time between recharges. And it’s getting worse, not better - housing has spiked up lately.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: 300A needs 500 kcmil cable.

Ampacity chart here: https://www.cityelectricsupply.com/downloads/Ampacity%20Chart.pdf

It's a bit more complicated than that though, as you infer: to get 1kV service you need a commercial-grade connection to the grid, rather than the more typical 240V single phase. 480V or 600V 3 phase would be the more likely choice for that high power level you're considering.

Comment: Is _kcmil_ a typo or yet another ridiculous unit of measurement? kilo-centi-milli-inch?

Comment: Upvoted.  NEC 310-16 from the NFPA is where they get their numbers.  I might as well cite the original source.  And, generally we call it "gauge" not "thickness".

Comment: The latter, it seems. It's 'thousands of circular mils', that is, the total wire cross section expressed as multiples of 1-mil cross-section wires. https://ctlsys.com/support/ct_opening_size_vs-_conductor_size/ 500 kcmil works out to 0.707"/18mm in diameter

Comment: "mils" is used in the industry, and so is correct.  "thou" (as in thousandths of an inch) is the term used for the same length for machinists, and "mil" has its own meaning in artillery.  Gotta love the Imperial system. ("mil" is same as "thou" but one is used for electrical cables and the other is used for machinists). The word "mil" sounds like it is metric, but it isn't.

Comment: Board layout too, though that's getting more metric-ified as time goes on.

Comment: Wire gage goes down to 0, then 00, 000, and 0000. Sometimes it is written as 0, 2/0, 3/0 and 4/0. After that they switch to kcmil. 250 kcmil, 300, 350, 500 and so on. I believe 500 kcmil is around 23.5 mm in diameter.

Answer (score 1):

the answer to your question is 185mm2, but as you mentioned above there are so many challenges that face the EV future.
I also thought about some place where you can have extra 1 or 2 packages of the same type of your batteries, and exchange them when empty so your main batteries are always charged, and empty ones are always on charger.
but this solution also has so many challenges :)

Comment: Also, you'd probably want aluminum, because of its better price:resistance ratio.

Comment: totally agree and does better supporting high current